# What is the difference between cardinals and alephs?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

It is stated that by Zermelo’s theorem, every cardinal is an aleph. But what is the difference between cardinals and alephs? I thought that alephs were just a way to denote cardinals (just for notation), but then this theory doesn't make sense.

Comment: cardinals wear red caps, alephs wear black yarmulkahs.

Comment: Probably it might be useful where *it is stated*. In general it is good to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for the question. (Even though in this specific case you received good answers even without adding the source of the claim.)

Comment: For example, if you include in your post: "Something like this appeared in the lecture I am attending, see [here](http://www.vub.ac.be/CLWF/SS/Sets10-2015.pdf)", then somebody could be able to point out how Alephs were defined in one of the [previous lectures](http://www.vub.ac.be/CLWF/SS/Sets8-2015.pdf) and that Zermelo's theorem is [related to well-orderings](http://www.vub.ac.be/CLWF/SS/Sets5-2015.pdf).

Comment: I do not know whether this is really a course you are attending (I have just tried to google for formulation similar to the one in your question), but if it was, the above information might be useful for you. And link to the course materials could be useful to answerers, since they would see what you have already been taught.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is the axiom of choice.

The $\aleph$ numbers are the cardinalities of well-ordered sets: if $A$ can be well-ordered, then there is some least ordinal $\alpha$ which can be bijected with $A$, and this is the cardinality of $\alpha$ (and such ordinals in general are called "initial ordinals"). In case $A$ is infinite, we get an $\aleph$ number (and there's really nothing interesting to say about the cardinalities of *finite* sets).

But if the axiom of choice fails, *not every set can be well-ordered*! And so if we want to speak of the cardinality of a non-well-orderable set, we need to use something other than $\aleph$s.

---

At this point it's worth saying a few words about what cardinality is.

First up, we have the "equinumerosity" relation $\equiv$: we write "$A\equiv B$" if there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$. This is easy to define, and there's no problem with it if the axiom of choice fails.

Now what's the *cardinality* of a set $A$? Well, here's the idea: we want to associate some object $\vert A\vert$ to every set $A$, such that $\vert A\vert=\vert B\vert$ iff $A\equiv B$ (that is, $\vert A\vert$ is an $\equiv$-invariant: if you know what $\vert A\vert$ is, then you know what $A$ is equinumerous with). One natural choice (this one is due to Frege) is to look at the entire $\equiv$-class itself - e.g. the cardinal "$2$" is just the collection of all $2$-element sets. Unfortunately, this is a proper class, so this doesn't work well with ZFC.

Instead, we have to be a little ad hoc. The natural way to fix Frege's idea is via [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick): we let $\vert A\vert$ be the set of all sets equinumerous with $A$ *and of minimal rank*, and this is indeed a set (and we can think of it as an "initial segment" of the class Frege cares about). This definition, again, works independently of the axiom of choice (although it if we drop both choice and [foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), and in fact I think there's no good way to define cardinality in the absence of both axioms - instead, you have to work with the relation "$\equiv$" alone).

Now if $A$ is well-ordered, we can do better: as observed above, we can pick out a *specific set* which is equinumerous with $A$! And that's the $\aleph$ number of $A$. In the presence of choice, there's no reason to use the Frege-style definition above, and we simply equate "cardinality" with "$\aleph$-number". But if choice fails, [we can't find canonical representatives to measure the size of some sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53770/defining-cardinality-in-the-absence-of-choice), so we have to do something more involved, like Scott's trick (and note that at the linked question there is some argument for the Scott approach actually being *more* natural, which I have some sympathy with).

Comment: There is very much that is really interesting about the cardinalities of finite sets. Normally though, we think of it as being about numbers, not cardinals.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Indeed. For example, one such interesting result about cardinalities of finite sets is this: If $N,A,B,C$ are non-empty finite sets, with $A.B$ disjoint, then the cardinality of the set of maps from $N$ to $A$ union the set of maps from $N$ to $B$ can only equal the cardinality of the set of maps from $N$ to $C$ if there exists an injective map $N\to\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - indeed. One must be quite wiley to prove that.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen 20 minutes it took me. Evil person.:D Very cool formulation though.

Comment: Say we drop foundation as well, so Scott's trick fails, are you familiar with *any* result that could not just be phrased in terms of $\equiv$?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Nope. The equinumerosity, as far as I know, by itself does everything we want cardinals to do in "core" mathematics.

Comment: What if we include non-core math and fringes of set theory also? Still no? With choice I would disagree with your above comment since the $\aleph$ numbers *give* us sets with large cardinalities, so having them as canonical representatives is quite useful.

Comment: In other words is Scott's trick a gimmick?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku This isn't the only thing Scott's trick is good for. It's also the way we make sense of e.g. ultrapowers of the whole set-theoretic universe.

Answer (score 11):

Well. The finite ordinals are also cardinals, but they are not $\aleph$ numbers.

But without the axiom of choice, there can be sets which cannot be well-ordered, and therefore their cardinality cannot be "measured" using $\aleph$ numbers. In that case we fallback to Scott cardinals, which allow us to define cardinals even in the absence of choice, for any set.

Comment: Argh, good point re: finite sets - forgot that in my answer!

Comment: To quote Nelson Muntz, Ha ha! :P

Comment: +1, and [I approve of Simpsons references.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2040694/28111)

Comment: Alessandro Andretta gave a talk in Arctic Set Theory 2017 that used that package, by the way.